# Multisite wp-admin redirecting to main wp-admin using NGINX

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, redirect, nginx

When I try to go to the wp-admin of any multi site, it redirects to the main wp-admin.

So if I go to `example.com/multi-site-slug/wp-admin/` it redirects to `example.com/wp-admin/`

NGINX is being used as a reverse proxy.

I'm using the standard WordPress Multisite Subdirectory rules per the codex: https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/

If I take out this line in the conf file `rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;`, it prevents the redirect but then media assets don't serve properly on the multisites.

NGINX vhost:

```
server {

    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 ssl http2 ;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location ~* \.(ico|jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|svg|tiff|exe|dmg|zip|rar|7z|docx?|xlsx?|js|css|less|sass|scss|ttf|woff2?|mp3|mp4|mkv|avi|mov|mpe?g|aac|wav|flac)$ {
        expires 7d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate";
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache "STATIC/TYPE";
    }

    location ~ "^(/wp-content/uploads)" {
        expires 7d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate";
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache "STATIC/PATH";
    }

    if ($http_cookie ~ "(_logged_in_|items_in_cart|jsid)") {
        set $cache_bypass 1;
    }

    location ~ "^(/.*login\.php|.*/xmlrpc\.php|.*/wp-cron\.php)" {
        limit_req_status 429;
        limit_req zone=example_com burst=8 nodelay;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_no_cache 1;
        proxy_cache_bypass 1;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;


        proxy_ssl_verify off;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_ssl_name $http_host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443;
    }



    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_no_cache $cache_bypass;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cache_bypass;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;


        proxy_ssl_verify off;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_ssl_name $http_host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443;
    }


    location ~ ^/files/(.*)$ {
      try_files /wp-content/blogs.dir/$blogid/$uri /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 ;
      access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 24h;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ^~ /blogs.dir {
        internal;
        alias /home/example/public_html/wp-content/blogs.dir ;
        access_log off; log_not_found off;      expires max;
    }


    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
        rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
        rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/purge(/.*) {
        proxy_cache_purge example "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
    }
}
```

The WordPress site is located at: `/home/example/public_html/`

Comment: I know you mentioned you are using the standard nginx sub directory rules, but could you provide the full snippet of your nginx config, and provide the path your wordpress install sits at relative to your site

Comment: Craig Pearson I have updated it.

Comment: Are you missing map blocks or did you just not post them?

Comment: I just post them.

Comment: You have to mention people with @username otherwise they don't get notified. Does that mean you have the map blocks of the nginx configuration?

Comment: @Nicolaisorry, my phone was messing up. Yes I have the map blocks,  I just didn't include them in this post.

Comment: @bigmike7801 Did you ever figure this out? Having the same issue and have a spent a few hours troubleshooting without success